# Remainder of a series converges uniformly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $B \subset \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ and $p \geq 1$. Suppose
$$
\sup_{u\in B}\sum_{n=0}^\infty |u_n|^p \leq 1,\qquad \sup_{u\in B}\sum_{n=0}^\infty |u_{n+1}-u_n|^p\leq 1
$$
Is it true that
$$
\sup_{u\in B}\sum_{n > N} |u_n|^p\overset{N\to\infty}\rightarrow{} 0\quad?
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $e^{(n)}$ the sequence whose $n$-th term is $1$ and all the others $0$. Then both two conditions are satisfied (up to a constant), but not the conclusion.